# I type php artisan make:migartion ... and php artisan migrate, but table was not created

Tags: laravel-5

I create laravel5,mysql8 environment with docker-compose.
I create post table with laravel migration.
but I entered mysql container and checked if the table was created, but the table was not created.

I type php artisan make:migration create_posts_table and It works.
Then, I did the following.
[image]

as pictured, table is not exist.
why is this?
Thank you for your help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: And what did `php artisan migrate` say when you ran it? What does `create_posts_table.php` look like? What does `select * from migrations` have in it?

Comment: sorry, I missed your comment.
I didn't mean any ill will.
Thank you for advice.

Answer (score 0):

have you run migrate in terminal? and check your table name

```
php artisan migrate
```

or check your env for db name

Comment: I ran php artisan migrate.
and db name is test in env file.
I added env file to my question.

Comment: check name table, in the question you create table posts not post @sorasakamoto

Comment: and one more, all tables in laravel end with 's', so when the model name is "student" it points to the table "students", if you don't want an "s" at the end you can set it in the model @sorasakamoto

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I l wiil look up this specification.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help. For future reference, this sort of "have you tried" response is much better as a comment on the question. That way, the thing that actually helped can be an obvious and prominent answer.